# Why are axions considered cold dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter, axion

Why are axions considered cold dark matter? They have a very low mass and if I'm not wrong they decouple before BBN, and in some models even earlier than neutrinos, they they should definitely be relativistic at the moment of decoupling and therefore Hot dark matter.

So why aren't they cold dark matter?

Comment: @RobJeffries Yes, thank you. I'm sorry I didn't search for an answer carefully enough